# Is it possible to add more than 1 card in response?

Tags: actions-on-google

I am using cards to show output to the user. I can only be able to show maximum of two chat bubbles and one card. But i want to add more than one card to the intent response in the webhook. I am using nodejs webhook using actions-on-google npm module, is there a way i can add more than one card in the response in single turn?
**My use case is, i want to show multiple images in the response.**

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not. Basic Card can be only rich response element on response. If you want to show more than one element you may consider to use Table Card element.

Here is the all fields you can use with Table Card. You can remove some of fields.

```
conv.ask(new Table({
  title: 'Table Title',
  subtitle: 'Table Subtitle',
  image: new Image({
    url: 'https://developers.google.com/actions/images/badges/XPM_BADGING_GoogleAssistant_VER.png',
    alt: 'Alt Text'
  }),
  columns: [
    {
      header: 'header 1',
      align: 'CENTER',
    },
    {
      header: 'header 2',
      align: 'LEADING',
    },
    {
      header: 'header 3',
      align: 'TRAILING',
    },
  ],
  rows: [
    {
      cells: ['row 1 item 1', 'row 1 item 2', 'row 1 item 3'],
      dividerAfter: false,
    },
    {
      cells: ['row 2 item 1', 'row 2 item 2', 'row 2 item 3'],
      dividerAfter: true,
    },
    {
      cells: ['row 2 item 1', 'row 2 item 2', 'row 2 item 3'],
    },
  ],
  buttons: new Button({
    title: 'Button Text',
    url: 'https://assistant.google.com'
  }),
}))
```

Also, you can use Carousel or Browsing Carousel for multiple cards with touch selection option. But, don't forget, you need use these element with option response or web urls.

For more information:

[Google Assistant Responses](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#table_cards)

Comment: I want to show more than one image in the response. I cannot use carousel because there is not user action from the response that i am providing @snuffbox.

Comment: There is no option to do that, since AoG wants assistants should be VoiceFirst.
I don't know what's your use case but using browsing carousel and linking the image's url to them may help. In case of touching carousel it just shows image. I know, it is not an efficient way to that, yet it may solve your problem.